# Change UITableView background color

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I know this question has been asked before but all the solutions I could find failed, I tried using "background = nil" method, I've tried override func UIColor and non of these methods work. When I run my app it has a red background but all the cells in the table view have white backgrounds. I am not using any prototype cells. I've also changed the background color in view and section index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try use "cell.backgroundColor" in cellForRowAtIndexPath. ˆ_ˆ

Comment: @Sirko Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Please try this :-

```
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

in the UITableViewDataSource protocol implementation

```
cellForRowAtIndexPath
```

Comment: where do I place: cell.backgroundColor = Uicolor.clearcolor() because it gives an error when putting it into the viewDidLoad function. I also tried saying tableView.cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearcolor()  but still gives me a error